# how to add my own templates to eclipse in play! framework editor

Tags: eclipse, templates, playframework

I've noticed that the play plugin for eclipse adds a play editor, 
along with several useful templates 
I'd like to add my own ones, but I couldn't find the way to do it 
I go to window, preferences, web, html files, templates and I can add 
templates to eclipse html editor, but I couldn't find a similar option 
for play editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source code for the play plugin :
https://github.com/playframework/playclipse/tree/master/source/templates

You might want to fork it and add your templates to that file. That is what I would do. But I do not have enough Eclipse development knowledge to help you further than point the direction.

Comment: I had a look at the xml file you pointed to, there's only one template to be used in the controller, I was thinking about all the templates for the template editor, I'll have a look at the code...

Answer (score 0):

I had a lok at the source, it seems like the template editor tags are defined here

https://github.com/playframework/playclipse/blob/master/source/src/org/playframework/playclipse/editors/html/HTMLEditor.java

looks like there's no support for creating your own templates thru eclipse...